# to find the mean max of the heap

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, heapq

```
I number : insert number to the q
<br/> D 1 : Delete the max value from heapq
<br/> D -1: Delete the min value from heapq
```

This is the condition 
so when

```
[I 16,D 1]   return [0,0]
[I 7,I 5,I -5,D -1] return [7,5]
```

I tried it with this way but some test case is not passed 
is there why to fix this code and if there is better approach let me know

```
import heapq

def solution(operations):
    answers = []
    answer_max = []
    answer_min = []
    arr_max = []
    arr_min = []
    try:
        for ope in operations:
            o,n=ope.split(" ")
            n = int(n)
            if o=='I':
                heapq.heappush(answer_max,(n,n))
                heapq.heappush(answer_min,(-n,n))
            elif o=='D':
                if n==-1:
                    if len(answer_min)==0: continue
                    else:
                        if len(answer_min)==1:heapq.heappop(answer_min)
                    heapq.heappop(answer_max)
                elif n==1:
                    if len(answer_max)==0: continue
                    else:
                        if len(answer_max)==1: heapq.heappop(answer_max)
                    heapq.heappop(answer_min)
        arr_min = [a[1] for a in answer_min]
        arr_max = [a[1] for a in answer_max]
        
        arr_max = [a for a in arr_max if a in arr_min]
        answers = [arr_min[0], arr_max[0]]
        return answers
    except: return [0,0]
```

Comment: why `[I 16,D 1]   return [0,0]` and not `return []`? Can you give a minimal reproducible example of the problem? Actually, the whole question is hard to comprehend. Can you revise to make it more clear?

Comment: oh when there is nothing on the list return [0,0] and when during the process when there is nothing and delete it just pass that operation.